# .keypress() isn't working how i thought it would

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedDay = '#selected_day';
    $(function () {
        $("#date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
            altField: selectedDay,
            altFormat: "DD",
            onSelect: function () {
                $(selectedDay).change()
            }
        });
        $('#selected_day, #times, #name, #group_number, #e-mail, #phone, #additional_info').change(function () {
            if ($(selectedDay).val() == '') {
                $('#times').fadeOut(500);
            } else {
                $('#times').fadeIn(500);
            }
            if ($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday') {
                $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').hide();
            } else {
                $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').show();
            }
            $('#confirm').text('You have chosen ' + $('#date').val() + ' at ' + $('#times').val() + '. This will be booked under the name of ' + $('#name').val() + ' for ' + $('#group_number').val() + ' people. We will contact you on either your phone number (' + $('#phone').val() + ') or your e-mail address (' + $('#e-mail').val() + ') to confirm your booking with us. Thank you for choosing Buddha Belly');
        });
        $('#phone').on('keypress', function () {
            $('#confirm').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

at the bottom you will notice that i want the confirm div to fade in when a key is pressed in the phone input field. Yet this doesn't happen, i have to type something and then click elsewhere in the document. Can you shed any light at all?

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/c3u5B/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#confirm` element fades in with a simple key press, as you want it to, the problem is that it's still empty when it does.

You might want to call the function you have on `change` on `keyup` too.

[Fast demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4jLra/)

Comment: I see your demo, that works how i need it to yet if you populate the phone field you'll see its 1 character behind. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes : use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. The `keyup` event is send after the field has been updated.

Comment: absolutely perfect, i wasn't aware you could run simultaneous function types, thanks so much :)

Comment: any reason why it stops my time drop down from changing it's output in the confirm div? Every other input works okay, but the drop down doesnt

Comment: I fastly demonstrated the concept, but you should declare separately the function and don't call it on keyup for other inputs. If my comment isn't clear, tell it and I'll edit the fiddle.

Comment: but everything else works perfectly as it should, i need all the others to update the confirm div if they value is changed. Only the time select box is broken, if you could update that'd be handy :)

Comment: Thank you so much, life saver!